# Excel Pivot Tables for multiple tags

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I'm using Excel 365.  I have a program that exports Excel files, and one field is a bunch of tags, separated by commas.

Let's say it looks something like this:
[image]

The program allows multiple tags (there's maybe 20 that could be changed in the future) to be selected as ingredients for each kind of candy.  It is not a consistent number, though they seem to always be alphabetical.

I'm looking to make some kind of table by ingredient and chef, according to time, like this:

[image]

I'm trying pivot tables, but they come back with long ingredient lists, when I really want just one item per line.  I also tried making an additional column for each ingredient, which searches the main column and returns yes or no based on if it's in the ingredients column.  It's still not working to have a single item listed each row with pivot tables- it gets into lots of levels and sublevels that way.

It's very likely there will be more ingredients and chefs in the future, so I'm trying to stick to some pivot tables where people can push "refresh all" to get the new ones.  Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you can build your ingredients list manually and add the names across the top then you can calculate the totals using a SUMIFS formula.

```
=SUMIFS($F$2:$F$5,$B$2:$B$5,"*"&$A10&"*",$C$2:$C$5,B$9)
```

if you put the formula above in cell B10 then autofill across and down then the values will be calculated automatically.

To break it down so you understand what's going on

```
=SUMIFS(**$F$2:$F$5**,$B$2:$B$5,"*"&$A10&"*",$C$2:$C$5,B$9)
```

is the range you want to sum under the total column.  It's locked using $ so it doesn't change when you autofill.

```
=SUMIFS($F$2:$F$5,**$B$2:$B$5**,"*"&$A10&"*",$C$2:$C$5,B$9)
```

The range you want to check with the tags in each cell, also locked.

```
=SUMIFS($F$2:$F$5,$B$2:$B$5,`"*"&$A10&"*"`,$C$2:$C$5,B$9)
```

The cell containing the ingredient you want to count with a star at each end to act as wildcards so it can return true when the cell contains the ingredient.  The column is locked.

```
=SUMIFS($F$2:$F$5,**$B$2:$B$5**,"*"&$A10&"*",**$C$2:$C$5,B$9**)
```

last bit is the range of the chef list (locked) and the criteria above locked by row.

I can't think of a way to automate the ingredient list but hopefully the formula will help.